# why does lightning always come from the clouds?

Tags: electricity, lightning

I read in my school textbook that lightning strikes the ground because the buildings or trees gets charged by induction.so why dosent the static discharge go from the ground to the clouds?

Comment: I suggest that you raed the Wikipedia article on lightning which does explain the complex nature of a lightning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does lightning always come from the clouds?

It doesn't.

> So why doesn't the static discharge go from the ground to the clouds?

It does sometimes.

Lightning is fairly complex, and there a several phases to a typical cloud-to-ground (CG) strike.  So even within CG lightning, you have to be pretty specific what exactly you mean by "come from"... Are you referring to the leader or the return stroke?

But to answer your question more generally, there are typically [three different types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Types) of lightning:

1. Cloud to Ground
2. Cloud to Cloud
3. Intra-Cloud

Comment: 2 should be Ground to Cloud surely?